# How to set BIND DNS server to listen on UDP port 53?

Tags: dns, bind

My BIND DNS server is configured to listen on TCP port 53. Is there any way to set the server to listen on UDP instead of TCP? The output of the netstat command is:

```
root@ns1:/# netstat -lntu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 192.168.163.172:53      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 10.1.100.41:53          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:12519           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39933           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 192.168.163.172:53      0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 10.1.100.41:53          0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 :::47282                :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::25334                :::*
```

Comment: How you check that your DNS server listen only on tcp? Please provide output from command: `netstat -unl | grep 53` or `ss -unl | grep 53`.

Comment: root@ns1:/# netstat -unl | grep 53
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 192.168.163.172:53      0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 10.1.100.41:53          0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                               
udp6       0      0 :::25334                :::*

Comment: As you see, your BIND listening on udp too :)

Comment: I am using netstat -lntu command to check the ports which are listening.. The output shows that the server is only listening to tcp on port 53.. Is it possible to configure the server to listen on both upd and tcp port 53?

Comment: @I.Khan Take the netstat output and add it to your post as an **edit**.  From what little I can tell so *far* you *are* listening on port 53.  By default, BIND9 *always* listens on both UDP and TCP port 53.  (And I would know, I run a cluster of 5 bind9 servers to serve all my sites' DNS)

Comment: I have edited my question and provided the netstat output. As can be seen the server is only listening on tcp and not on udp

Comment: you seem to be confusing socket state, which is a TCP thing, with "listening" or not. Since you used "-l" in your command you are only showing "listening" stuff.

Answer (score 4):

This is the important line from your `netstat` output relevant to the question you ask about UDP port 53 being listened on or not:

```
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*
```

This is indicative that something is listening on port 53 UDP.  This is *probably* `bind9`.  Usually I use `sudo netstat -tulpn` which points me at what process is using what, but this *looks* like it's your BIND9 server.

All the items in your `netstat` output are actually *listening* for connections.  TCP has states, but UDP doesn't, so it won't show `LISTEN` at all in the last column.  However, the above line I mentioned *indicates* something is listening on port 53 UDP.

(You might want to run `sudo netstat -tulpn` to see what process is actually listening on port 53, if you're really curious, but it's more than likely this is `bind9`)

Comment: And please don't disable the TCP port 53. It is crucial for the DNS server to run, as TCP is used in zone transfers. When the data can't fit in a single UDP frame, TCP is employed then.